# Cisco Autonomous AP - Snmp clients Monitoring (connected and not connected)

Tags: snmp, cisco, oid

We have more than 1000 Cisco Aps already deployed (SAP1602, AP1042, AP1041 models) and we would need to get some data from them through some snmp querys.

We would like to know if it would be possible to get the following data and in case it would be possible, if someone could help us to identify the correct OIDs to get the following data.

SAP1602

- Number of devices (not connected) Devices detected around          - Is it possible (YES/NO)
- Number of associated devices                                                           - Is it possible (YES/NO)
- MACs of all detected clients                                                              - Is it possible (YES/NO)
- MACs of all associated devices                                                         - Is it possible (YES/NO)
- RSSI of all detected clients                                                                - Is it possible (YES/NO)
- RSSI of all associated clients                                                            - Is it possible (YES/NO)

AP1042

- Number of devices (not connected) Devices detected around          - Is it possible (YES/NO)
- Number of associated devices                                                          Is it possible (YES/NO)
- MACs of all detected clients                                                              - Is it possible (YES/NO)
- MACs of all associated devices                                                         - Is it possible (YES/NO)
- RSSI of all detected clients                                                                - Is it possible (YES/NO)
- RSSI of all associated clients                                                            - Is it possible (YES/NO)

AP1041

- Number of devices (not connected) Devices detected around          - Is it possible (YES/NO)
- Number of associated devices                                                          - Is it possible (YES/NO)
- MACs of all detected clients                                                              - Is it possible (YES/NO)
- MACs of all associated devices                                                         - Is it possible (YES/NO)
- RSSI of all detected clients                                                                - Is it possible (YES/NO)
- RSSI of all associated clients                                                            - Is it possible (YES/NO)

Thank you,

Regards,

**Jordi!**

Comment: Does not look like a programming question to me. Questions on enterprise IT or network management belong on Serverfault.com.

Comment: Thanks Jolta for your appreciation, I saw questions related to SNMP or OIDs in this forum too.

Comment: Yes @Jordi Riba but neither of those are programming languages or programming tools. SNMP is a networking protocol slash network management framework, OIDs are just strings...

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at the configuration of Access Points on the Cisco IOS software that helps you identify which access points traps you can use for the SNMP? Click here [cisco link](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/access_point/15_2_4_JA/configuration/guide/scg15-2-4_book/scg15-2-4-JA-chap18-snmp.html#40992)!  and look at the table 18-4 which gives a list of notifications you can use and to configure a trap manager that will help you receive them. The directions underneath the table 18-4 clarifies how to implement the snmp traps that can assist your queries.

Hope that helps,
JC

Comment: Hi James, 
First of all, thanks for you answer. 
We know how to enable traps and how to query through snmpwalk for example. What we were trying to know if it's possible to get some information about non connected stations (Number, MACS, RSSI). And in case it's possible, we would like to create an script that querys all our APs and store all received data in a Postgres sql database. Thks!

Answer (score -1):

You are really asking "what MIB objects give me the information I require?".
For that, you need to understand the Cisco MIBs on those devices, and then
search for any MIB objects with which you can derive the info you require.
Someone might point you at sample objects, but this is really work you need
to do.

Comment: Thanks Gambit Support. Yes, thats true. I've been looking through Cisco MIBs tree and I've found some of these values but not been able to find others so just would like to know if someone else has never tried it before. From what I've been investigating I could say that I could be able to get all information related to associated stations but I've no idea about non-associated stations. And believe me, I've been googling and reading a lot before posting. Do you have any idea about if it's possible to get that information regarding not connected stations? Thanks!

Comment: No sorry. But you will get MUCH better results to your query if you give more info, eg. what you have already found.